# Query temporarily shows records that dont match criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a dashboard form in MS access 2010. This dashboard has a subform datasheet view query which shows outstanding Purchase Orders, where the status' can be `submitted`, `overdue` or `part delivered`. There is also an option for `delivered` but this isn't in the criteria of the query as they are not "outstanding".

I have another user, who on their front end, is updating deliveries (saving to backend on server). what I see on my front end, is Purchase orders that now have status `delivered` on my query result.

As I understand the status has been 'updated' and my query results clearly change, but, it is only when I perform an action that requeries the subform when they disappear.

- When my query results show `delivered`, why is this update not removing the records straight off?
- is this 'update' different to a requery?
- does this update occur directly after the other user changes the record?
- Why do I see `delivered` despite criteria?

I can post the SQL query but I don't think its necessary??

Thanks

Comment: have a look at: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Refresh-or-requery-data-76e8c8b5-b8b4-49eb-a7d5-a472e742366c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was essentially confusing the difference between Refresh and Requery.

Refreshing records only updates the data that already exists in the datasheet form. It does not display new records, or remove deleted records and records that no longer meet the query criteria.

Requery, as the name suggests, re-runs the query to find what data records meet the query criteria specified for the datasheet form.

I have added a timer to requery my subform regularly, but I have decided that I will simply allow the data to exist until the user performs a database action where I have set a requery to occur.

Answer (score 1):

The criteria for your subform will only filter out that record when you requery it.

Since you have a split database, you will be unable to add a command to the update routine your coworker is using to requery your control. However, you could set your subform to requery automatically at specific time intervals, so if the data is updated by someone else, the "delivered" record will only appear until the next timed requery command executes. That removes any need for you to actively requery your subform when you notice bad data.

[Check out this link on Time Intervals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836371.aspx) or for further help check out [this thread.](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=195940)